# Spacy performance degradation on upgrading to version 2.2

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have been working on an application using a custom spacy NER with python 3.4 and spacy 2.0.11, I have then upgraded to python 3.7 and spacy 2.2.2. For this upgrade, I had to retrain the spacy model as there is backward incompatibility. However on upgrading, the performance of the model went down considerably. Any idea why this could have happened.

-> The training loss which was less than 1 is now around 70. 
-> On sample data, the old model extracted 250 entities while the new one extracts around 170.

For training the custom ner, I have followed the standard code as given on spacy’s website.

Comment: Are you training from scratch or fine tuning? spaCy model 2.2 was adapted to handle lower case entities as well as other improvements. Are you aligning your spaCy version with your model version (if you don't train from scratch)?

Comment: I’m training from scratch.

Comment: I suggest to open an issue on the spaCy repo